# image appear and disappear when using windowlisteners

Tags: java

when i use window listeners to Call a class, the image prodused appears on my canvas and then shortly after disappears. I do not have the same problem when i use listeners like mouseclicklistener or actionperformedlistener. I would like for the image to appear automaticly when i first open the program. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

```
    private void nyttkart(){
    vindu = "&WIDTH=" + bredde + "&HEIGHT=" + høyde;
    bbox = "&BBOX=" + String.valueOf(vestl) + "," + String.valueOf(sørl)
            + "," + String.valueOf(østl) +"," + String.valueOf(nordl);
    try {
        URL kart = new URL("http://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.topo4?VERSION=1.3.0"
                + "&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&FORMAT=image/png"
                + "&SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=Hoydelag,Arealdekkeflate,"
                + "Vannflate,Vannkontur,Elver,Hoydekurver,Veger,Jernbane"
                + bbox + vindu);
        InputStream is = kart.openStream();
        Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
        canvas1.getGraphics().drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SOSI_Utvalg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SOSI_Utvalg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how painting works.  You don’t tell a Canvas to give you a Graphics;  rather, you override a paint method and the system invokes that method when it needs you to paint.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ for details.

That said, you don’t need a Canvas to show an image:

```
Component imageComponent = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(kart));
```

If you want to receive IOExceptions when the image cannot be loaded, you can load the image first, and pass that instead:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(kart);
Component imageComponent = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

As a side note, String.valueOf is implicitly called when concatenating objects to form a String.  You don’t need to call it explicitly:

```
bbox = "&BBOX=" + vestl + "," + sørl + "," + østl +"," + nordl;
```